# controlTextDidBeginEditing is not being called when NSTextField is selected

Tags: macos, nstextfield

controlTextDidBeginEditing delegate method is not being called when NSTextfield is selected by clicking or by pressing tab.The delegate is set and all other delegate methods are fired.Any suggestions??

Comment: Post code snippet here. Another suggestion is to debug and verify that  the text field is becoming first responder.

Comment: hi i found out the problem later... actually this method gets fired only when we start editing or typing text into the textfield...otherwise it wont get fired...now i am searching for another method which gets fired when the textfield is selected itself... either by tab or mousedown

Comment: You may be looking for this method `setFieldEditor:`

Comment: ok thanks i were trying to subclass the nstextfield and write a custom delegate when the tab is pressed... for this in subclass i wrote the code like 
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"keyPressed on TextField");
    NSLog(@"%d",[theEvent keyCode]); //if(keycode==tabevent) //[self.delegate tabPressed];
}  but even this method is not getting called keydown should work for all responders right?

Comment: The method that is in my previous comment should be suffice. Whenever key event happens on a responder, `keyDown:` method should get called.If you are overriding `NSTextfield` then you can try   implementing 'becomefirstresponder` method.

Comment: hi thanks a lot ....it worked.. can you put it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle key events like Tab key press can be handled by writing `setFieldEditor:` method in the delegate method.For this requirement this method is suffice.

Another method is to override the `NSTextfield` class and writing `keyDown:` method.